# Get IGrouping data in Repeater ItemDataBound

Tags: linq, repeater, igrouping

I am wanting to group news articles by year in a repeater. The format would be:

2010

list of articles

2011

List of Articles

My access layer returns a flat list of news articles, specifically List.  Therefore, I am grouping them and binding them to the Repeater as follows:

```
        events = DAL.GetEvents(); 
        var groupedNewsList = from e in events 
            group e by e.StoryDate.Year 
            into g 
            select new { 
                Year = g.Key
                , Events = g 
            };

        rptEvents.DataSource = groupedNewsList;
        rptEvents.DataBind();
```

The problem is trying to get the List from within the ItemDataBound event. So far, I have the following:

```
        var data = e.Item.DataItem;

        System.Type type = data.GetType();
        // getting the year works fine
        string year = (string)type.GetProperty("Year").GetValue(data, null).ToString();
        // this returns something, but I can't access any properties. I need to get 
        //access to the contained List<News>
        var newsList = type.GetProperty("Events").GetValue(data, null);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You don't *have* a `List<News>` - you just have a *grouping*. If you want a `List<News>`, you'll need to change your query, e.g.

```
var groupedNewsList = from e in events
                      group e by e.StoryDate.Year into g
                      select new { Year = g.Key, Events = g.ToList() };
```

Note that if you're using C# 4 you could do reflection rather more easily using `dynamic` typing:

```
dynamic data = e.Item.DataItem;
string year = data.Year.ToString();
List<News> newsList = data.Events;
```

Alternatively, you could avoid using an anonymous type in the first place - create your own `GroupedNewsList` type with `Year` and `Events` properties, populate that in your query, and then cast to it in your event handler.

Answer (score 1):

The "sender" object in the ItemDataBound event is the repeater -- use it to get to the data-source.  If the data-source has been grouped before binding, you can compare the current value to the previous value & hide the year-field if they are equal.  Like this:

```
MyObject item = (MyObject)item.DataItem;
Repeater repeater = (sender as Repeater);
List<MyObject> items = repeater.DataSource as List<MyObject>;

Label lblGrouping = (Label)item.FindControl("lblGrouping");
if (item.ItemIndex == 0 || item.DateField.Year != items[item.ItemIndex - 1].DateField.Year) {
    lblGrouping.Text = item.DateField.Year.ToString();
}
```

This worked for me, as I used a table with each row being one item, and the left-most column contained the "lblGrouping" control.